# What is a synonym for canary? (being a fail bird that dies as an warning indicator)

Tags: synonyms, figures-of-speech

[Online](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/canary) we have five different meanings for canary:

- having the color of a canary; of a light to moderate yellow
- any of several small Old World finches
- a female singer
- a moderate yellow with a greenish tinge
- someone acting as an informer or decoy for the police

I have a sixth:

- a fail bird that dies as an warning indicator

My question is: **What is a synonym for canary? (being a fail bird that dies as an warning indicator)**

Comment: Whre did you take the sixth definition from?

Comment: Are you after something like *cannon fodder*?